# How to handle Ruby find command return undefined method `[]' for nil:nilclass (nomethoderror)

Tags: ruby, null, find, puppet, puppet-enterprise

I’m using the Ruby find command to collect the information I need from the Puppet Database as below.

```
vm_name = puppetdb.find { |details| details['certname']==(hostname) and details['name'] == 'az_metadata' }['value']['compute']['name']
```

Some of the parameters don’t have ‘az_metadata’ parameters, and that causes the find function to show “undefined method `[]' for nil: nil class (no method error).” How can I handle those or undefined method values from the find result for that specific variable?

How can I handle those or undefined method values from the find result for that specific variable?

Comment: What do you expect it to return when there are no `az_metadata` parameters? Just `nil`? A fallback value? Raise a proper error message?

Answer (score 1):

From the error, it seems the value to a key in the results is `nil`.

You can use [dig](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Hash.html#method-i-dig) method or the [Safe Navigation Operator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Safe+navigation+operator)

```rb
# dig
data = puppetdb.find {|details| details['certname']==(hostname) and details['name']=='az_metadata'}
vm_name = data.dig('value','compute','name')

# Safe Navigation
data = puppetdb.find {|details| details['certname']==(hostname) and details['name']=='az_metadata'}
vm_name = data&.['value']&.['compute']&.['name']
```

Comment: Hi Borjagvo,

Thanks for providing the useful information. However I got error from both dig and safe navigation. Probably my ruby version ruby 2.0.0p648 is too low? Below are the errors.

undefined method `dig' for #<Hash:0x00000002004810> (NoMethodError)

syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting keyword_end
vm_name = data&.['value']&.['compute']&.['name']

Comment: You are right. Your Ruby version is too old. You have two options. Either upgrade your Ruby version or use other methods to evaluate whether the value exists or not (if/else, fetch method, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

> Some of the parameters don’t have ‘az_metadata’ parameters, and that causes the find function to show “undefined method `[]' for nil: nil class (no method error).” How can I handle those or undefined method values from the find result for that specific variable?

Test whether the result is `nil` before trying to access its elements?  There are fewer ways to do that in Ruby 2.0 than in some later versions, but any version you're likely to be able to put your hands on should accept this:

```rb
result = puppetdb.find { |details| details['certname']==(hostname) and details['name'] == 'az_metadata' }

vm_name = result.nil? ? nil : result['value']['compute']['name']
```

You can of course substitute a different default value for the case where `puppetdb.find` returns `nil`.

Of course, if you cannot rely on the result to have a `'value'`, and that to have a `'compute'` then the problem occurs again, and you might need to do the above multiple times.

Alternatively, if you scope it narrowly enough, it could be reasonable to just rescue the `NoMethodError`:

```rb
result = puppetdb.find { |details| details['certname']==(hostname) and details['name'] == 'az_metadata' }

begin
  vm_name = result['value']['compute']['name']
rescue NoMethodError
  vm_name = nil
end
```

Note, however, that that leaves it ambiguous what was `nil`, and that it would also catch cases where the result or one of the other intermediate values was non-`nil` but also did not have a `[]` method.